# mdnsd drains a lot of battery power in Xiaomi Redmi Note 4G. How do I find out which app calls it to run?

Tags: battery, xiaomi-redmi-note-4g

I have a Xiaomi Redmi Note 4G, and for few days my battery drains as hell. I checked the running processes, and found that the cause is `mdnsd`.

Is there a way to find which app calls this process to run?

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:] [image: IMG:]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not permament solution, but so far the best solution.

On rooted phone :

1. use ES File Explorer (or any File Explorer with Root access)
2. go to device/system/bin
3. select the mdnsd file
4. open properties
5. open permissions
6. uncheck the execute permissions
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

În my case it was Xiaomi's Uniplay Service, which I've frozen, rebooted and the simptom went away. You have to be rooted to be able to disable or uninstall Xiaomi apps and services.

Comment: not in my case...